# Unsuccessful in trying to convert a column of strings to integers in Python (hoping to sort)

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am attempting to sort a dataframe by a column called 'GameId', which are currently of type string and when I attempt to sort the result is unexpected.  I have tried the following but still return a type string.

```
TEST['GameId'] = TEST['GameId'].astype(int)
type('GameId')
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It helps to get a better answer if you provide some code to reproduce your problem (not just what you tried) see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

One way to make the data life easier is using dataclasses!

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

# here will will be calling the dataclass decorator to send hints for data type!
@dataclass
class Columns:
    channel_id    : int
    frequency_hz  : int
    power_dBmV    : float
    name          : str

# this class will call the data class to organise the data as data.frequency data.power_dBmV etc
class RadioChannel:
    radio_values = ['channel_id', 'frequency', 'power_dBmV']
    def __init__(self, data): # self is 'this' but for python, it just means that you mean to reference 'this' or self instance
         self.data = data # this instances data is called data here
         data = Columns(channel_id=data[0], frequency=data[1], power_dBmv=data[4], name=data[3]) # now we give data var a val!
    def present_data(self):
         # this is optional class method btw
         from rich.console import Console
         from rich.table import Table
         console = Console()
         table = Table(title="My Radio Channels")
         for item in self.radio_values:
              table.add_column(item)
         table.add_row(data.channel_id, data.frequency_hz, data.power_dBmv)
         console.print(table)
         # ignore this if its confusing

# now inside your functional part of your script

if __name__ == '__main__':
    myData = []
    # calling an imaginary file here to read
    with open("my_radio_data_file", 'r') as myfile:
        mylines = myfile.readlines()
        for line in myline:
            myData.append(line)
        myfile.close()
    #my data would look like a string ["value", value, 00, 0.0, "hello joe, from: world"]
    ch1 = radioChannel(data=myData[0])
    ch1.present_data()
```

This way you can just call the class object on each line of a data file. and print it to see if it lines up. once you get the hang of it, it starts to get fun.

I used rich console here, but it works well with pandas and normal dataframes!
dataclasses help the interpreter find its way with type hints and class structure.

Good Luck and have fun!